# PowerBI, Conditional Formatting for Stacked Column Chart

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm a geologist and trying to create a "Stratigraphic Column" to visualize the progress of Drilling Rig and I realized that Stacked Column Chart is suitable for that visualization.

**Everything is perfect expect colors. Every lithology has their own color but PowerBI assign random colros to them. There is no any "Conditional Formatting" button in chart properties. That project is very critical for me, is there any code for that or is there any other tool to create something like Stratigraphic Column in PowerBI?**

Thats what I want to create similar;

[image]

This is my final progress in PowerBI;

[image]

This is databse where I get data for chart;

[image]

Comment: You can check if in "more visuals" you find something useful for your purpose. If not, then You can create a new one:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/powerbi-visuals-tools    AND
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/visuals/develop-circle-card#creating-a-custom-visual

Comment: I don't think it is good to use `bar chart` for your presentation also, very messy on visual design because too much category is there

Answer (score 0):

Check if "Sankey Chart" helps.
As I see, there is a Source and Destination.
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/visual-awesomeness-unlocked-sankey-diagram/